# How did 'licentiare' semantically shift to mean employment dismissal?

Tags: etymology

I was researching the etymology for the French  *licencier*, and [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/licencier) refers to Latin *licentiare*. I can't see it exhibited in [*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.ca/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199580316)

[image]

but [Latdict](https://latin-dictionary.net/definition/25643/licentio-licentiare-licentiavi-licentiatus) does.

[image]

1. Please see the title.
2. What notions underlie authorization with employment termination? Perhaps this is [auto-antonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Typology_by_Blank_(1999)), but I can't brainstorm how authorization/permission with its positive connotation would be semantically related to employment dismissal that undoubtedly disheartens the employee!

Comment: Re: _What notions underlie authorization with employment termination_, I think it has got to do with the military: you end your military service, and are given _permision_, which in practice means the end of it.

Answer (score 2):

The term "licentiare" comes from medieval, not classical Latin. The OLD, as fine as it is, is mainly useless for medieval latin vocabulary. Better try the Dictionary of Medieval Latin Dictionary from British Sources (DMLBS), freely available at Logeion (https://logeion.uchicago.edu).

For "licentiare" (you must search for verbs in the infinitive, not in the 1st person present, as in most other Latin dictionaries), the DMLBS shows entries as early as 12th century. See here: https://logeion.uchicago.edu/licentiare

The DMLBS' third sense of the term is this:

> 3 to give leave (to depart), dismiss. b to send on leave, grant
>   furlough, to disband (army); (~are ad propria) to send home. c to
>   dismiss, expel (from office, service, community, or sim.). d to remove
>   or expel (from one’s land), dispossess. e to dissolve (parliament);
>   cf. departire 2a.

which seems akin to the French "licencier".